# Prisma queryRaw don't work with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, prisma

I'm trying to import a csv file via prisma in a mysql database using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" but it doesn't work.

```
  const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 1.csv
  INTO TABLE Temp
  CHARACTER SET UTF8
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '\"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 2 LINES`

Raw query failed. Code: `1064`.
```

Does prisma is able to use "LOAD DATA LOCAL.." or is there any restriction?

Comment: It looks like a problem in the syntax of the LOAD DATA statement. Try: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '1.csv' ...`.

Comment: if using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '1.csv'`  I'm receiving `Raw query failed. Code: 1295. Message: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Comment: No more syntax problems. Check [Security Considerations for LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html) and [No way to specify a MySQL local-infile option](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12913).

Comment: Can you try invoking executeRaw instead of queryRaw? Check this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/12913

Comment: Same error with executeRaw as well.. `Code: 1295. Message: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Comment: According to the Prisma documentation, it's currently not possible to execute that statement using `$executeRaw`. See [Prisma Client :: Raw database access :: $executeRaw](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#executeraw:~:text=Prisma%20Client%20submits%20prepared%20statements%2C%20and%20prepared%20statements%20only%20allow%20a%20subset%20of%20SQL%20statements.%20For%20example%2C%20START%20TRANSACTION%20is%20not%20permitted.%20You%20can%20learn%20more%20about%20the%20syntax%20that%20MySQL%20allows%20in%20Prepared%20Statements%20here.).